# DataMapper 'datetime' field format

Tags: ruby, rubygems, datamapper

```
require 'active_support' # for Time.now.to_s(:db)
require 'user' # user.rb has DataMapper 'property :registered_at, DateTime'

p Time.now.to_s(:db)

ob = User.create(
    :id => 1, 
    :login => 'login',
    :registered_at => Time.now.to_s(:db)
)

p ob
```

I am getting result:

```
"2011-03-10 16:21:41"
#<User @id=1 @login="login" @registered_at=Thu, 10 Mar 2011 16:21:41 +0000>
```

But 'registered_at' value is not I've expected, what's the reason of this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Datamapper handles probably re-parses the date into a proper Ruby object so you can use and manipulate it. You don't have to take care of the right date/time format for the DB, Datamapper will handle it for you.

You can also leave the `.to_s(:db)` out, as Datamapper will know what to do with it.

```
ob = User.create(
    :id => 1, 
    :login => 'login',
    :registered_at => Time.now
)
```

Comment: DataMapper seems to be doesn't know how to manipulate this data format, because when I am doing `p ob.save` i am getting `false`, so there are warning because of data format, in my opinion.

Only `p ob.save!` overrides warning and saves data into mysql table

Comment: `User.create` already writes the user to the db. Calling `ob.save` is redundant as the object is already persisted and has not changed in the meantime. Look at this guide at the very bottom: http://datamapper.org/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

You declared :registered_at property to be a DateTime hence DataMapper will always convert every non-DateTime value into a DateTime object. Why do you pass a string as a value?

Comment: But what sould I pass? I just need to store DateTime value in row, nothing more

Comment: Pass a DateTime object or a string that can be parsed by DateTime class.

Instead of Time.now.to_s(:db) use DateTime.now